# How can I make a formula in Google Spreadsheet to return a value if a cell contains a text in a list

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm currently interested in building a custom function/formula in Google Spreadsheet where the function will intake a cell and return a value that is related to a specific text in a list.
As you can see in the screenshot, which is a demo that I drafted to give a better idea of what I'm trying to accomplish, column A contains a list of items that has random texts. In the texts, there are some keywords that I would like to identify into different categories.

Column B is just a demo of how I envision to use my custom function that I want to create. Column C is the expected result that I would get by using the custom function.

Column E is the list of keywords that I would like the custom function to search for in cells and Column F is the category that I would like the custom function to return once it finds the relevant keyword in a text.

Thank you!

[image: Example1]

I tried searching for this topic, but I only came across how to set up an array formula to achieve what I want to do. If there was any post about this, I would really appreciate if you could just link it in the comment.

Answer (score 0):

Given your scenario, you can try with this formula:

```
=FILTER(F:F,INDEX(REGEXMATCH(A2,"(?i)"&E:E)),E:E<>"")
```

[image: a]

If you wish to have it for the whole row:

```
=BYROW(A2:A,LAMBDA(each,IF(each="","",FILTER(F:F,INDEX(REGEXMATCH(each,"(?i)"&E:E)),E:E<>""))))
```

[image]

If you could have more than one result, you can add JOIN:

```
=BYROW(A2:A,LAMBDA(each,IF(each="","",JOIN(", ",FILTER(F:F,INDEX(REGEXMATCH(each,"(?i)"&E:E)),E:E<>"")))))
```

[image]

Comment: hi thank you for your help! I'm trying to see if I can make a custom formula using apps script to accomplish what I'm trying to accomplish. I don't like using array formula because it spills into other rows. Would you happen to know how to set up a custom formula?

Comment: You can always narrow A2:A to the range you want, then it won't expand more than you wish. To set up a custom formula use this same formula and adapt it to make a [custom formula]("https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions?hl=en"). Just change the ranges you want to name them as variables. For example, if you name the variable as input, you can use: `=FILTER(F:F,INDEX(REGEXMATCH(input,"(?i)"&E:E)),E:E<>"")`